# All files in a single folder on USB flash drive replaced by a strange file

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, data-recovery

I have a 16GB USB flash drive which I've been working from for a while with no problems.

Today, I plugged the USB flash drive in only to discover that everything inside the folder with the files I've been working on has been replaced by a single file called 'A' (no extension). All of my other files appear untouched.

What happened to my files, and can I recover them?

Comment: Simplest explanation is either they've been encrypted by a virus, or the drive has failed. Fix is to bin the USB stick & replace from your backup. Don't put the new drive back in that machine until you have eliminated the possibility of a virus. (I know this is going to be followed by "I don't have a backup" & advice to never entrust the only copy of any file to such a delicate medium, or indeed to ever keep only one copy of any data you don't consider temporary… )

Comment: Gladly I have a backup of (most) of the files, but since many of those that were erased are ones I've been working on from the USB itself, I don't have up to date backups of all of them. I'm just very confused as to why this happened to just one folder (all other folders appear to be perfectly fine), and what the 'A' file is.